# Is it possible to create a word TOC in the format of a table?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I want to create something like this

[image: TOC]

Is it possible using the TOC feature?

Comment: Looking at the default TOC and customised design, it doesn't appear that you can add columns. Perhaps you can embed a TOC into a table, then move the heading 2 data around.

Comment: Pretty sure that if you want automatic ToC generation, you would have to generate the ToC, then turn that into a table with the formatting you want. To do that reliably will probably need code, e.g. VBA.